# Is it possible to redirect two times?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

Is it possible -using only **JavaScript** and **HTML**- to have 3 pages with the following?

In Page1 there would be a button that when clicked it would redirect to Page2 for X seconds, and then redirect to Page 3.

I know it is possible using JavaScript in each page and timers, but what I don't know is if it can be done in one single JavaScript code in Page1, something like a timer and then redirect to the third page.

Comment: can i ask why do you want to do it? why don't you load page 3 directly when the user clicks the button?

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you actually want to achieve, there could be a better solution than a series of redirects (e.g. AJAX calls).

Comment: Sounds like a click-fraud requirement. Pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, no. But then immediately contradicting myself: You could do it using frames, but I'm with [Ixg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3908235/lxg) when he/she [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821784/is-it-possible-to-redirect-two-times#comment40395095_25821784) there's likely to be a better way to achieve your ultimate goal.

Basically, to do it with frames: The click on Page1 doesn't take you off Page1, but instead replaces Page1's content with an `iframe` that fills the entire page, loading its content from Page2. Then since the JavaScript environment of Page1 still exists, you can use a timer to redirect to Page3 when ready, all without any modifications to Page2 or Page3 (unless of course Page2 has frame-busting built into it).

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this scenario can be implemented in one single page.

Say you have three pages, you want `page1.html` to redirect on click

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page 1</title></head>
  <body>This is page 1. <input type="button" onclick="toPage2()" value="Go to page 2." /></body></html>
```

to `page2.html`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page 2</title></head>
  <body>This is page 2.</body></html>
```

and then have `page2.html` redirect to `page3.html`, after some time

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page 3</title></head>
  <body>This is page 3.</body></html>
```

All you need to do is get the source of page 2, inject some javascript into it and then load the source into the browser; this means page 2 does not need to be aware of the redirect behaviour. Thus, page 1 would become something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page 1</title>
    <script>
        // you can get the source of page 2 via ajax -- still meeting the requirement of javascript/html only.
        var source2 = '<html><head><title>Page 2</title></head><body>This is page 2.</body></html>';

        function toPage2 () {
            var page2 = document.open('text/html', 'replace');
            var source2injected = inject(source2, 3000, 'page3.html');
            window.history.pushState('', '', 'page2.html');
            page2.write(source2injected);
            page2.close(); }

        var left   = "<script>setTimeout(function(){window.location='",
            middle = "';},",
            right  = ");</scr" + "ipt>"; 
        function inject (source, time, destination) {
            return source.replace('<body>', left + destination + middle + time + right + '<body>'); }

         </script></head>

  <body>This is page 1. <input type="button" onclick="toPage2()" value="Go to page 2." /></body></html>
```

I am not saying that this is a good idea or the right solution for the problem you are actually trying to solve, but it does answer your question.